# Join & Update Notifications

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, email, upgrade

How can you tell if someone joins a mailing list (selects from a checkbox option in custom fields)?

How can you tell when someone updates their contact preferences?

Comment: You may do better in terms of StackExchange protocol to ask as two separate questions

Comment: They are related, so I do not see a reason to separate them.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the extension CiviRules to do that.

You need to set up two different Rules, one for each process.

Select a trigger and condition with your requirements (group contact is added, and contact is changed, would be the triggers I think)

Dependent on your preference, you could create one of these actions:

- a scheduled activity assigned to a backend staff
- a tag (that could be shown in a report on your dashboard)
- send you an email (then you need to install the Email API as well, and choose to send email to alternate email adress)
- send you an sms (then you need to install the SMS API as well, and choose to send sms to alternate phone number)